# IntelliJ or Eclipse refactoring all usages of a method to a method on a different class/interface

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, automated-tests, refactoring

Java class `com.company.session.old.SessionContext` is used throughout our code base among other in the following way (around 1k usages):

```
import com.company.session.old.SessionContext;

...
SessionContext ctx = SessionContext.create();
```

I would like to migrate it to a new implementation, which would read:

```
import com.company.session.SessionContext;
import com.company.session.SessionContextManager;

...
SessionContext ctx = SessionContextManager.instance().create();
```

Imports are easy to migrate with full text search and replacement. The migration of the actual call `SessionContext.create(` to `SessionContextManager.instance().create(` could also be done that way. Now the problem is that this would leave `SessionContextManager` **not imported** and one would need to open all those files with replacements to auto-organise imports.

Does IntelliJ or Eclipse provide functionality to search for all usages of a method and replace that with a completely different method not via plain text search but via some code processing mechanism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA, the easiest way to perform this refactoring is to change the implementation of `SessionContext.create()` so that it calls `SessionContextManager.instance().create()` and then to inline the method. You can restore the old implementation after the inline has updated all the usages.